# Overflowing text onto the next line in a Grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a Grid where I have defined the Height as 50, and then displaying a bunch of labels bound to a List. How can I overflow the Labels from row to row instead of what's happening now which is squeezing the Labels vertically?

public List LabelList { get; set; } = new List
    {
        "Cat",
        "Dog",
        "Fox",
        "Leopard",
        "Bear",
        "Monkey",
        "Lion",
        "Bison",
        "Alpaca",
        "Sheep",
        "Ant",
        "Fox",
        "Tiger",
        "Elephant",
        "Mouse",
        "Eagle",
        "Coyote"
    };

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>


<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" />

<StackLayout
    Grid.Row="1"
    BackgroundColor="Beige"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LabelList}"
    Orientation="Horizontal">

    <Label
        Padding="2"
        BackgroundColor="Blue"
        FontSize="Large"
        Text="{Binding}" />
</StackLayout>


<StackLayout Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" />
```

What is happening now:
[image]

What I want to achieve (this is photoshopped):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use FlexLayout instead of StackLayout

```
    <FlexLayout
        Grid.Row="1"
        BackgroundColor="Beige"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LabelList}"
        Wrap="Wrap">

        <Label
            Padding="2"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            FontSize="Large"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding}" />
    </FlexLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like?:

```
<StackLayout
    Grid.Row="1"
    BackgroundColor="Beige"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LabelList}"
    Orientation="Horizontal">

    <Label
        Padding="2"
        BackgroundColor="Blue"
        FontSize="Large"
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        Text="{Binding}" />
</StackLayout>
```

From what I gather, you haven't set your `LayoutOptions` for the labels you are trying to stack.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout

Comment: I had tried that, and it didn't work. In fact, I went down the list of every option available for HorizontalOptions and nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display UI like the screenshot, you can take a look the following code:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" />
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="1"
            BackgroundColor="Beige"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LabelList}"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>


        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" />
```

[image]